# How to combine Spring Boot HornetQAutoConfiguration and CachingConnectionFactory?

Tags: jms, spring-boot, hornetq, spring-jms

Migrating from Spring Boot 1.1.4 to 1.2.3 we have the following issue:

In our Spring Java configuration under 1.1.4 we combined `org.springframework.jms.connection.CachingConnectionFactory` with the jmsConnectionFactory templated by `org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jms.hornetq.HornetQAutoConfiguration` and it worked fine.

Under 1.2.3 HornetQAutoConfiguration has been heavily reworked, which now leaves us wondering how to configure the use of CachingConnectionFactory without writing the whole configuration from scratch.

Is the scenario still valid to use CachingConnectionFactory with HornetQ in Spring Boot to cache JMS `Session`s and `MessageProducer`s?

If the answer is yes, how can CachingConnectionFactory be configured under Spring Boot 1.2.3?

Should this question be transformed into a Spring Boot issue?

Comment: Note: under 1.1.4 there was flexibility due to the public method `HornetQAutoConfiguration.jmsConnectionFactory()` that is no longer available under 1.2.3. It was possible to subclass HornetQAutoConfiguration and call that method via super in terms of a factory method, and then wrap the result with CachingConnectionFactory.

Comment: The easiest way I see is to just create a `BeanPostProcessor` which checks if a bean is a `ConnectionFactory` and then wraps it in a `CachingConnectionFactory`, this would work with any JMS implementation, without extending any particulier Spring Boot classes. (This should work regardless of the Spring Boot version).

Comment: It's indeed tricky to wrap an auto-configured bean in your customizations. I think we can envision an issue of supporting `CachingConnectionFactory` or opening the API a bit to offer such support. Please create an issue

Comment: Thanks, I opened an issue: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/2956

Answer (score 0):

This solution with own `BeanPostProcessor` worked for me. You can enable  the caching of `ConnectionFactory` with a property `jms.useCachingConnectionFactory = true` in your application.properties.

```
@ConditionalOnProperty(prefix = "jms", value = "useCachingConnectionFactory", havingValue = "true", matchIfMissing = false)
public class CachingConnectionFactoryDecoratingPostProcessor implements BeanPostProcessor
{

    @Override
    public Object postProcessBeforeInitialization(Object bean, String beanName) throws BeansException
    {
        return bean;
    }

    @Override
    public Object postProcessAfterInitialization(Object bean, String beanName) throws BeansException
    {
        if (bean instanceof ConnectionFactory)
        {
            return new CachingConnectionFactory((ConnectionFactory) bean);
        }
        return bean;
    }
}
```